# ExtJS - autoScroll doesn't show in nested grid

Tags: extjs, autoscroll

I've been trying to find an answer to this problem for the last 24 hours and couldn't find a way to resolve this. Here it is:

I'm using MVC architecture with ExtJS 4. I have a tabpanel that has some grid as items. When these grids load, they do not have a vertical scrollbar, even though I set autoScroll to 'true' and their content is bigger than the screen can show. Every post I read about this problem was resolved setting the grid's parent layout to 'fit', but, as you can see below, I already done it and still not have a scrollbar... If I define a height to the grid, the scrollbar works perfectly, but I need it to work with different heights...
I belive I might have a overnesting problem, but I just started developing with ExtJS some days ago and it stills a little confusing to me...

The question is: how can I make this structure work with autoScroll?

SO won't let me post an image here as my reputation is lower than 10, [so you can find my app's structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoMzf.png)

Please note that I wrote "layout: 'fix'" in the image, but I meant "layout: 'fit'" :)

This is my Main view, which has 2 panels. The 'center' one is where I load the tabpanel that has the grid.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

requires:[
    // 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    // 'Ext.layout.container.Border',
    'MyApp.view.Menus'
],

xtype: 'app-main',

layout: {
    type: 'border'
},

items: [
    {
        region: 'north',
        xtype: 'panel',
        padding: '5 5 0 5',
        title: 'MyApp',
        items: {
            xtype: 'menus'
        }
    }, 
    {
        region: 'center',
        itemId: 'centerPanel',
        xtype: 'panel',
        padding: 5,
        layout: 'fit'
    }
]
});
```

This is the view that have the fieldset and the tabpanel as items:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.licencas.List', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'licencaslist',
title: 'Licenças de software',
border: false,
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        title: 'Dados do Ve&iacute;culo',
        margin: 5,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                anchor: '100%',
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'descricao',
                store: 'ComboEmpresas',
                typeAhead: true,
                queryMode: 'local',
                name: 'empresa',
                fieldLabel: 'Empresa'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                editable: false,
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'descricao',
                store: 'ComboSoftwares',
                queryMode: 'local',
                name: 'software',
                fieldLabel: 'Software'
            },
            {
                name: 'valor',
                fieldLabel: 'Valor empresa:',
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 100000,
                allowDecimals: true,
                disabled: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'contrato',
                fieldLabel: 'Contrato:',
                xtype: 'textfield',
                disabled: true,
            },
            {
                name: 'demonstracao',
                xtype: 'checkbox',
                fieldLabel: 'Demonstra&ccedil;&atilde;o',
                disabled: true,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        xtype: 'licencastabpanel',
        border: false,
        margin: 5
    }
],

initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments)
}
});
```

And finally this is the grid where I need the autoScroll property...

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.licencas.placas.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype: 'licencasplacaslist',
store: 'EmpresaVeiculos',
border: false,
forceFit: true,
autoScroll: true,
plugins: [new Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing({
    clicksToEdit: 1,
})],
dockedItems: [
    {
        dock: 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [
            {
                text: 'Alterar todos',
                iconCls: 'money-16',
                action: 'alterartodos',
                xtype: 'button'
            },
            '->',
            {
                xtype: 'trigger',            
                name: 'searchfieldLicencasPlacas',
                itemId: 'searchfieldLicencasPlacas',
                emptyText: 'Filtrar por placa...',
                width: '500px',
                hideLabel: true,
                selectOnFocus: true,
                triggerCls: 'x-form-search-trigger'
            }                     
        ]
    }
],
columns: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
    {       
        text: "Placa",
        dataIndex: 'placa',
        width: 70
    },
    {       
        text: "Serial",
        dataIndex: 'serial',
        width: 70
    },
    {
        text: "Condutor",
        dataIndex: 'condutor'
    },
    {
        text: "Ativo",
        dataIndex: 'ativo',
        width: 50
    },
    {
        text: "Data In&iacute;cio",
        dataIndex: 'data_inicio',
        format: 'd.m.Y',
        width: 60
    },
    {
        text: "Data Fim",
        dataIndex: 'dt_fim',
        format: 'd.m.Y',
        width: 60,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            format: 'd.m.Y'
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Contrato",
        dataIndex: 'contrato',
        width: 70,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Software",
        dataIndex: 'valor_software',
        renderer: 'usMoney',
        width: 70,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 1000,
            allowDecimals : true
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Comunicação",
        dataIndex: 'valor_comunicacao',
        renderer: 'usMoney',
        width: 70,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 1000,
            allowDecimals : true
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Comodato",
        dataIndex: 'valor_comodato',
        renderer: 'usMoney',
        width: 70,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 1000,
            allowDecimals : true
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Empresa para faturar',
        dataIndex: 'fatura',
        width: 200,
        editor:
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                displayField: 'descricao',
                valueField: 'descricao',
                store: 'ComboFaturas',
                name: 'software',
                queryMode: 'local'
            }

    }
],

initComponent: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments)
}
});
```

Please, note that I removed all "layout: 'fit'" (except from the Main view, which has influence over other views) from the code as it wasn't working anyway... :)

Please, let me know if I need to provide you any extra information. I tried to make it easier to understand with the image below.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Please post your code, and specify the ExtJs version you are using, then it will be easier to help you

Comment: You're right, I didn't post the code before because I thought it would be too much... I edited the post with the code... And I'm using ExtJS 4. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

It works as follows:

1. grid ignores `autoScroll` config option
2. grid needs a height, either explicit or controlled by a layout of its parent container
3. if grid does not have a height, it tries to expand itself vertically according to the number of records loaded in the store so that it does not show the scrollbar
4. `fit` layout can only have one item - if it is a grid then its height (and width) is controlled by the size of the parent container

To summarize: If you want a grid to scroll it must have a height.

Comment: Hi Saki! Thanks for your reply... I wanted to control my grid's size according to it's parent container, so I need to define it parent's container layout to 'fit', right? But would it work if this parent container already has a "parent container" that have 'fit' layout?

Comment: Yes, you can nest containers in containers, but do not do so unnecessarily. Also, care that each level of nesting has some `layout` configured.